# Numpy кол-во знаков после запятой

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Мне нужно вычислить матрицу Гильберта с заданной точностью (например, 10 знаков после запятой). Размер матрицы 3 чисто для примера, так то буду брать больше.
Моя программа:

```
import numpy as np

def hilbert(n):
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError("Matrix size must be one or greater")
    elif n == 1:
        return np.array([[1]])

    v = np.arange(1, n + 1) + np.arange(0, n)[:, np.newaxis]
    return 1. / v

n = 3
alpha = 1e-10
H = hilbert(n)
E = np.identity(n)

print(H)
print(alpha*E)
```

Получается:

```
[[1.         0.5        0.33333333]
 [0.5        0.33333333 0.25      ]
 [0.33333333 0.25       0.2       ]]
[[1.e-10 0.e+00 0.e+00]
 [0.e+00 1.e-10 0.e+00]
 [0.e+00 0.e+00 1.e-10]]
```

Хотелось бы (вместо точек нужное кол-во знаков, в данном примере должно быть 10 знаков после запятой):

```
[[1.0...0         0.50...0         0.33333333...3]
 [0.50...0         0.33333333...3  0.250...0     ]
 [0.33333333...3   0.250...0       0.20...0     ]]
[[1.e-10 0.e+00 0.e+00]
 [0.e+00 1.e-10 0.e+00]
 [0.e+00 0.e+00 1.e-10]]
```

Comment: Как вариант, вручную перебрать и вывести массив для каждого элемента вызвав форматирование с 10 знаками после запятой, типа: `"{:.10f}".format(0.33)`

Comment: Помог ли вам ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `np.set_printoptions(precision=10, floatmode='fixed')`

```
[[1.0000000000 0.5000000000 0.3333333333]
 [0.5000000000 0.3333333333 0.2500000000]
 [0.3333333333 0.2500000000 0.2000000000]]
[[0.0000000001 0.0000000000 0.0000000000]
 [0.0000000000 0.0000000001 0.0000000000]
 [0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000001]]
```